# Throwing a coin $n$ times probability question

Tags: probability

We throw tails with probability $p$. We are throwing a coin until we throw tails or until we throw $n$ times. $X$ is a random variable denoting the number of throws.
I do understand that for $X = n-1$, we get $$P\{X=n-1\}=P\{H,H,H,...,H,T\} = (1-p)^{n-2}p$$
But I do not understand the following:
$$P\{X=n\}=P\{ \{H,H,H,...,H\}\{H,H,H,...,H,T\} \} = (1-p)^{n-1}$$

Can somebody explain the second result?

Comment: The second is not correct. It should be $(1-p)^{n-1}$

Comment: @MathLover Yes I will edit, can you explain why is it that way

Comment: Because there are $n$ throws at max. So if $(n-1)$ throws are all $H$ then the $n$th throw happens and it does not matter what the last throw is ($H$ or $T$).

Comment: Or add both cases: $HHHHHH....H$ or $HHHHHH...T$ . $P(X = n) = (1-p)^{n-1} (1-p) + (1-p)^{n-1} p = (1-p)^{n-1}$

Comment: @MathLover I see now it makes sense if we add both cases

Comment: The second case is the same as P( n-1 heads). You've written P(n heads or n-1 heads then tails).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t. the $X_k$ are IID Bernoulli with probability of heads $P(X_1=1)=p$. Define the stopping time $\tau_n=\inf\{k \in \mathbb{N}:X_k=0\}\wedge n$. We want to find the distribution of $\tau_n$: we get
$$P(\tau_n \leq k)=P\bigg(\bigcup_{j\leq k}\{X_j=0\}\bigg)=1-\prod_{j \leq k}P(X_j=1)=1-p^k$$
$$\implies P(\tau_n=k)=1-p^k-(1-p^{k-1})=p^{k-1}-p^k=p^k(p^{-1}-1)=p^{k-1}(1-p)$$
for $k \in \{1,2,...,n-1\}$ and
$$P(\tau_n\leq n)=1\implies P(\tau_n=n)=1-P(\tau_n \leq n-1)=1-(1-p^{n-1})=p^{n-1}$$

Comment: We havent taken everything you written in lectures. For example what is stopping time? What is IID?

Comment: @VLC IID means independent and identically distributed: it's usually the case for repeated coin throws. A stopping time is a random variable, for example [read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time); it's used to model events in a sequence.